Как создать список из сообщений пользователя в библиотеке aiogram в python
Всем привет! Такая проблема: пишу бота в тг, нужно чтобы он создал список из сообщений пользователя и отправил мне.
async def call_app(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await callback.answer('')
    await callback.message.answer(text=f'Хорошо, начнем заполнять анкету.'
                                       f' Выберите необходимые услуги и затем нажмите готово.',
                                  reply_markup=kb.design_keyboard)
    await state.set_state(StatesForm.GET_SERV)


@router.message(StatesForm.GET_SERV)
async def get_services(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    #тут должна быть функция наполнения списка 

@router.message(StatesForm.GET_SERV, F.text == 'Готово')
async def get_service(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(text=f'Как вас зовут?',
                         reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    await state.set_state(StatesForm.GET_NAME)


@router.message(StatesForm.GET_NAME)
async def get_name(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(name=message.text)
    await message.answer(f'Теперь нажмите на кнопку ниже, чтобы поделиться контактом.',
                         reply_markup=kb.contact_keyboard)
    await state.set_state(StatesForm.GET_NUMBER)


@router.message(StatesForm.GET_NUMBER, F.contact)
async def get_contact(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(number=message.contact.phone_number)
    await message.answer(f'Ваша заявка на консультацию сформирована, в скором времени с вами свяжется наш специалист.',
                         reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    data = await state.get_data()
    await message.bot.send_message(chat_id=settings.bots.admin_id, text=f'Новая заявка:\n' #Тут бот отправляет мне сообщение 
                                                                        f'\t\t\tИмя: {data["name"]}\n'
                                                                        f'\t\t\tНомер: {data["number"]}\n'
                                                                        f'\t\t\tВиды услуг: {data["list"]}\n')
    await state.clear()


И в чём у вас проблема, к чему этот огрызок кода?

Как написать хендлер, который будет запоминать выбор пользователя и затем отправлять мне? Выбор осуществляется через Reply клавиатуру, так что в итоге отправляется текстом.
